# Why does Rails change the color escape sequences of the logger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, colors

I have a simple ruby script with a logger and I've set a formatter for that logger to provide a colored output:

```
require 'colorize'
require 'mono_logger'

logger = MonoLogger.new(target_file)
logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
  meta = "#{severity.to_s[0].red} #{datetime.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N').white}"
  "#{meta}  #{msg}\n"
end
```

That works great, all `logger.info` calls are saved with the correct color escape sequences and displayed red/white on black when viewing the file with `tail`.

Within that ruby script I load a rails environment in order to access the applications models etc like this:

```
require File.expand_path('../../../../config/environment',  __FILE__)
```

After that line each log call doesn't save correct color escape sequence. It seems like rails does some substitutions or something like that.

Before the `require`:

```
\033[0;31;49mI\033[0m [0;37;49m14-09-19 15:38:36.472544\033[0m  Starting boot process
\033[0;31;49mI\033[0m [0;37;49m14-09-19 15:38:36.472788\033[0m  Loading rails environment
```

After the `require`:

```
\033[1;31mI\033[0m [1;37m14-09-19 15:38:39.949944\033[0m  Using config config/config.rb
\033[1;31mD\033[0m [1;37m14-09-19 15:38:47.105813\033[0m  Setting up clockwork
\033[1;31mI\033[0m [1;37m14-09-19 15:38:47.805399\033[0m  Setting up EventMachine
```

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Rails has it's own `.green`, `.blue`, ... methods for String. If you use `.colorize(:green)` instead of `.green` everything works like a charm.